# Does not work if condition, where is wrong code?

Tags: android

```
if (cevabb.getText().toString() == cev0.getText().toString()) {     
    Toast.makeText(test.this,"aaaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
} else {
    Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

`cevabb.getText().toString()="xxx"` and `cev0.getText().toString()="xxx"`, but message shows "bbb"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String.equals()` method for `String` comparison, because `==` compares the references, whereas `equals()` is used for content comparison.

```
if(string1.equals(string2)){
    // DO Something
}
```

Your case:-

```
if(cevabb.getText().toString().equals(cev0.getText().toString())){
    // DO Something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use like this.

```
if (cevabb.getText().toString().equals(cev0.getText().toString())) {

....

}
```

Difference between == and equals() method.

== is used to compare the reference. and equals method check the content of string variable.

Example.

First example

```
String s1 = "FirstString";
String s2 = "FirstString";

 if(s1 == s2) {
    //This condition matched true because java don't make separate object for these two string. Both strings point to same reference.
 }
```

Second example

```
String s1= "FirstString";
String s2 = new String("FirstString");

if(s1.equals(s2)) {
  //This condition true because same content.
}

if(s1 == s2) {
  //This condition will be false because in this java allocate separate reference for both of them
}
```

Conclusion: Java check whether string exist or not. If we create the object of second string using new and have different content then its creates object and assign different reference and In case of If we don't create the object using new and have same content then its assign the same reference as first string contain.

Answer (score 3):

`cevabb.getText().toString()==cev0.getText().toString()`

has to be

`cevabb.getText().toString().equals(cev0.getText().toString())`

or if you want to compare as object

use `intern()`

`cevabb.getText().toString().intern()==(cev0.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 2):

= operator compares the reference of String in memory.
So, it is possible that String with the same value are located at different memory location
and = operator gives result false.

Use equals or equalsIgnorecase so that it compares the value stored in String reference.